# Styling a NgFor horizontally

Tags: css, angular

How to horizontally  display each `<ng-container>` of an *ngFor directive.

I have:

```
<div *ngIf="hasFinished">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let champ of champStats">
      <h2> {{champ[1].name}} </h2>
      <p> Level: {{champ[1].Level}} </p>
      <p> XP: {{champ[1].XP}} </p>
      <p> Time lost: {{champ[1].CharacterTimePlayed}} </p>
      <p> Wins: {{champ[1].CharacterWins}} </p>
      <p> Loosses: {{champ[1].CharacterLosses}} </p>
      <p> XP : {{champ.CharacterRanked2v2Wins}} </p>
      <p> XP : {{champ.CharacterRanked2v2Losses}} </p>

    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

I'm using bootstrap, I want that each element take a column of 4 (like the 3 first ones are in a row, the 3 after another row etc...)

Just like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <ng-container class="col-lg-4> ...
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container class="col-lg-4> ...
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container class="col-lg-4> ...
    </ng-container>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <ng-container class="col-lg-4> ...
    </ng-container>
    //...
</div>
```

EDIT: The other problem is : `if there is 7 elements, how to manage the last one? (for example)`

Comment: Why don't you use a div instead of ng-container?

Comment: Ok, I can use a div, but how to do 3 div on each row (automatically filled with the ngFor)

Comment: From the documentation on angular.io: The Angular <ng-container> is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

Comment: If you use just one row, with your 7 divs inside with class `col-lg-4`, then you should have 4 divs on the 1st line and 3 on the second

Comment: @SamehAwad ok I'll use div, but reconsider the problem I'm facing with div, how to manage it?

Comment: @David Didn't know that, thank you then

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this through CSS3 flex

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="horizontal" *ngIf="hasFinished">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let champ of champStats">
      <p> Name: {{champ.name}} </p>
      <p> Level: {{champ.Level}} </p>
      <p> XP: {{champ.XP}} </p>
      <p> Time lost: {{champ.CharacterTimePlayed}} </p>
      <p> Wins: {{champ.CharacterWins}} </p>
      <p> Loosses: {{champ.CharacterLosses}} </p>
      <p> XP : {{champ.CharacterRanked2v2Wins}} </p>
      <p> XP : {{champ.CharacterRanked2v2Losses}} </p>

    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height:100px;    
    width: calc(100% * (1/4) - 10px - 1px)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: flex` in CSS as:

**HTML**

```
<div class="horizontal" *ngIf="hasFinished">
    <div *ngFor="let champ of champStats">
      <h2> {{champ[1].name}} </h2>
      <p> Level: {{champ[1].Level}} </p>
      <p> XP: {{champ[1].XP}} </p>
      <p> Time lost: {{champ[1].CharacterTimePlayed}} </p>
      <p> Wins: {{champ[1].CharacterWins}} </p>
      <p> Loosses: {{champ[1].CharacterLosses}} </p>
      <p> XP : {{champ.CharacterRanked2v2Wins}} </p>
      <p> XP : {{champ.CharacterRanked2v2Losses}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the two divs *(class="row")* with inner divs *(class="col-lg-4")* using `<ng-container>`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let champ of champStats">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
           {{ champ.prop1 }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
           {{ champ.prop2}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
           {{ champ.prop3 }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4>
           {{ champ.prop4 }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4>
           {{ champ.prop5 }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4>
           {{ champ.prop6 }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4>
           {{ champ.prop7 }}
        </div>
    </div>

</ng-container>
```

And note that [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) doesn't render any DOM element in angular which means giving any html attribute to that directive are pointless.

Comment: you forgot to mention that for this you need bootstrap

Comment: @bokkie the OP already stated he is using bootstrap. So hence the styling is related to bootstrap.